# Cant make Tinymce edit iframe to work with tabbifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, tinymce

Im trying to get tinymce edit iframe to work with this wonderfull tabbifier:

http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber

I have successfully installed both of them and they work great.

In my example I have tested the following:

1. Load a tinymce component and save the following code inside the tinymce iframe with the HTML option:
   test
2. The result is saved perfectly after refreshing with F5 and this code is saved in the database:

> ```
> <p>test</p>
> ```

tinymce is working perfecly.

The next test I have made is with tabber:

1. Edit the tinymce component box and saved the following code with the HTML option:

> ```
> <div class='tabber' id='tabber1'>
>     <div class='tabbertab' title='FIRSTTAB' >
>         test firsttab
>     </div>
>     <div class='tabbertab' title='SECONDTAB' >
>         test secondtab
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

1. The code is perfectly saved in the database, and the result is perfectly loaded in the output view, showing two tabs, each one of them with its content.
2. The problem is while trying to edit the content again with tinymce, the tabs are not shown. The content is perfectly loaded in the tinymce iframe, without the tabs. Its shown as below:

   test firsttab

   test secondtab

The HTML code inside it is good, it has the proper tabbifier html code saved before.

The problem maybe is that the iframe of tinymce is not able to load or interpret the javascript of tabber.js and its not showing the tabs.
I have tested loading the javascript of tabber.js inside the tinymce iframe with this code, and seems to load it but the tabs are not still shown:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      tinyMCE.init({
        mode:                              "exact",
        elements:                          "%s",
        theme:                             "%s",
        %s
        %s
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location:   "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align:      "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing:           true
        %s
            setup : function(ed)
            {
                ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt)
                {
                    alert("entered tiny");
                    // Load a script from a specific URL using the global script loader
                    //tinymce.ScriptLoader.load('/js/tabber/tabber.js');
                    // Load a script using a unique instance of the script loader
                    //var scriptLoader = new tinymce.dom.ScriptLoader();
                    //scriptLoader.load('C:\tabber.js');

                    // Load multiple scripts
                    var scriptLoader = new tinymce.dom.ScriptLoader();
                    scriptLoader.add('/js/tabber.js');
                    scriptLoader.loadQueue(function() { alert('All scripts are now loaded.'); });
                });
            }
      });
</script>
```

I have also checked that /js/tabber.js is the correct path. And saw at firebug that its loading it.
The two alert messages are displayed, so it seems to load it, but the tabs inside the tinymce edit iframe are still not shown.

Any help is welcome, thank you so much.

Comment: You are trying to get tabs to work INSIDE the rich text editor - this makes no sense!  You should instead render editors inside of tabs.

Comment: Rich-text editors aren't meant to implement javascript applications.  They can render some HTML and some CSS.  But they are not browsers, they are text editors with added rich-text enhancing capabilities.

Comment: I understand it and that was the second thing I though if I couldnt get it to work. I tought that maybe tinymce had support to execute and render javascript output since it allow to execute javascript inside it with the scriptLoader.
Yes, as you said the best option will be to render one rich editor for each tab individually. I wanted to avoid that option since I didnt want to add many columns to my database, one for each tab with its rich content editor. But seems to be the only way, thank you so much :)

Comment: Its exactly as you explained Stefan, just tested it with CKEditor and it does exactly the same.

Comment: Glad if I helped. If you know your stuff it is probably possible to extend the capabilities of TinyMCE via it's API methods like those  provided by the scriptLoader class. Remember also that you can render multiple rich text editors per tab, so you can order all your form inputs, including the rich text editors you use, as is convenient for you.

Comment: This does not necessarily mean that you have to add columns to your database, even though it is generally a good idea to keep your fields separate as far as possible. It is possible to merge some field values into one field by using a unique separator to separate the individual fields - but only if you really must!  Then you can read the single field from the db and use php explode or js split to extract the individual field values.  But I would definitely recommend separate columns as far as possible, in general.

Comment: Don't fall into the trap of thinking that every form input MUST correspond to a database column.  There is a processing step in between saving from a form into a database, and another processing step between displaying data from a database onto a page.  The database columns should be designed to save only the necessary information in an easily accessible way.  The GUI interfaces and displays however, should be designed with the human user in mind.  In between you use programming scripts to process the data into the necessary formats either way.

Comment: Yes ty for the detailed explanation and suggestions. Probably I wont have to add many columns but Ill analyse it slowly for speed and optimization.

Answer (score 5):

The [tinymce ScriptLoader](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4%3aclass.tinymce.dom.ScriptLoader) does **not** load a script inside the iframe. It provide a way to load a script in the **main window** after the tinymce initialization. This is very confusing as not documented.

But you definitelty **can** load a script inside the iframe. Here is the magic :

```
tinymce.init( { setup : function( ed ) {
    ed.on('init', function (args) {
        // get the iframe DOM
        var doc = args.target.contentDocument || args.target.contentWindow.document;

        // inject script into the DOM
        var s = doc.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = '/js/tabber.js';
        doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
    });
});
```

Comment: you deserve a medal!

Answer (score 0):

Several browsers have problems with spaces and tabs on paragraph start.
A workaround for spaces is to code them onSave as protected spaces if they are at the beginning. The solution for tabs is to use another character with similar behaviour and replace them when saving. It is necessary to recode the content when reloaded from databse into the editor.

Comment: what is the browser you use mostly?

Comment: I am testing this issue with Firefox, Internet Explorer and Chrome lastest versions. The tinymce tags are not shown inside its editiframe in any of the browsers.

Comment: can you create a tinymce fiddle (http://fiddle.tinymce.com/) to demonstrate the pioblem?

Comment: Thank you for your interest Thariama. I have created a simple example here which clearly shows the problem:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/nocaab/24

Comment: it is as i said already - the browser kicks them out (like it does with spaces) at the beginning of a a paragraph

Comment: Please Thariama, if there is a way to solve it, could you give me more details about how should I encode the data into the database or decode it from the database, thank you so much.

Comment: can you show me the code that gets the db content and writes it back plus a portion of content with the specail character?